# Throw a stackoverflow from user code

Tags: c#, exception

Can a `StackOverflowException` be thrown from user codes:

```
public void Main(){
    throw new StackOverflowException();
}
```

StackOverflowExceptions have [interesting qualities](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2008/10/22/when-can-you-catch-a-stackoverflowexception.aspx) when you try to catch them. One of the examples in the linked article is a purposeful throwing of this exception. However, that doesn't seem to be possible. Have things changed?

Edit: Sorry, I mean I can't find `StackOverflowException` in the namespace `System`. The link does detail the the CLR can catch user generated SO exceptions.

Comment: BTW I came across this before I remembered [How to: Break When an Exception is Thrown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh.aspx) was a thing. I think you can see what I was trying to do.

Comment: What do you mean by "that doesn't seem to be possible"?

Comment: we can find the follwing in article referenced, This is not 100% true though.  User code can still handle StackOverflowExceptions which are artificially thrown.  That is thrown by the user instead of resulting from an actual overflow of the stack.

Comment: You can throw and catch `StackOverflowException` created by you. But there is special, reserved instance of it (stored on heap) which is used by .NET, which cannot by thrown and catch. Does it answer you question?

Comment: The CLR isn't that simply fooled by this.  SO is a serious mishap, jitting code and allocating objects is no longer safe to do.  So the CLR *pre-allocates* the SOE object.  Only throwing that specific object triggers the special handling.  You cannot get to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A StackOverflowException is an exception which should not be thrown by your self, it handles a special case when your runtime fails because of a programming fault. In 2.0 the runtime added some extra behavior to the StackOverflowException thrown by the .net runtime:

> In prior versions of the .NET Framework, your application could catch
> a StackOverflowException object (for example, to recover from
> unbounded recursion). However, that practice is currently discouraged
> because significant additional code is required to reliably catch a
> stack overflow exception and continue program execution.
>
> Starting with the .NET Framework version 2.0, a StackOverflowException
> object cannot be caught by a try-catch block and the corresponding
> process is terminated by default. Consequently, users are advised to
> write their code to detect and prevent a stack overflow. For example,
> if your application depends on recursion, use a counter or a state
> condition to terminate the recursive loop. Note that an application
> that hosts the common language runtime (CLR) can specify that the CLR
> unload the application domain where the stack overflow exception
> occurs and let the corresponding process continue. For more
> information, see ICLRPolicyManager Interface and Hosting Overview.
>
> Remarks
>
> StackOverflowException is thrown for execution stack overflow errors,
> typically in case of a very deep or unbounded recursion. The Localloc
> Microsoft intermediate language (MSIL) instruction throws
> StackOverflowException.
>
> StackOverflowException uses the HRESULT COR_E_STACKOVERFLOW, which has
> the value 0x800703E9. For a list of initial property values for a
> StackOverflowException object, see the StackOverflowException
> constructors.

[system.stackoverflowexception(MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stackoverflowexception(v=vs.110).aspx)